# How to set alternating color to nested and sibling divs with certain class.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nested list, each list item has a container div with class R
I am trying to apply alternating colors to alternate divs. The problem is that divs with class are not always siblings.

**This is my html:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="R">Bat</div>
        <div class="R">description</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="R">Cat</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="R">Rat</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="R">one
                    <div class="R">blah</div>
                    <div class="R">blah blah</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="R">two
                    <div>
            </li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**This is how I want it to look(I have harcoded colors with inline css)**

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="R" style="background-color:red;">Bat</div>
    <div class="R" style="background-color:green;">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R" style="background-color:red;">Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R" style="background-color:green;">Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R" style="background-color:red;">one
          <div class="R" style="background-color:green;">blah</div>
          <div class="R" style="background-color:red;">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R" style="background-color:green;">two
          <div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use different class for different color

Comment: Could you please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: @Amitsingh That is not going to work.. I mean I am adding elements dynamically.. for example : User can add item type A or Item type B. 
If I assign a class to type A :red and type B : green. It will still not work since the user can add type A twice.

Comment: @Tushar Yes, no problem with jQuery. Although CSS solution would be more desirable.

Comment: can you use `:pseudo` class like `:before` and `:after`

Comment: _"This is how I want it to look(I have harcoded colors with inline css)"_ At `<div class="R" style="background-color:red;">one` parent element would set `background-color` to `"red"` of child elements `<div class="R" style="background-color:green;">blah</div>
          <div class="R" style="background-color:red;">blah blah</div>` without `!important` set in `css` ?

Comment: @Tushar why did you remove your answer? I think you answered before Bhushan

Comment: @Arbaaz Bhushan's answer is better than using `each()` to loop

Comment: @Tushar yes but there is no harm in mentioning the alternative with a comment.. "Bhushan's answer is better"

Comment: @Tushar please see if you can help me with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367933/align-checkboxes-to-the-left-in-a-nested-html-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : you can use `:odd` and `:even` jQuery selectors to get odd and even divs and apply background color accordingly. See below code

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul div.R:odd').addClass('oddColor');
  $('ul div.R:even').addClass('evenColor');

});
```

```css
.oddColor {
  background-color: red;
}
.evenColor {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Bat</div>
    <div class="R">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R">one
          <div class="R">blah</div>
          <div class="R">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R">two
          <div>
      </li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".R:even").css("background-color", "green");
  $(".R:odd").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Bat</div>
    <div class="R">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R">one
          <div class="R">blah</div>
          <div class="R">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R">two</div>
      </li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul div.R:odd').addClass('oddRow');
  $('ul div.R:even').addClass('evenRow');
});
```

```css
.oddRow {
  background-color: red;
}
.evenRow {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Bat</div>
    <div class="R">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R">one
          <div class="R">blah</div>
          <div class="R">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R">two</div>
      </li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div.R').each(function(index) {
  $(this).css('background-color', index % 2 === 0 ? '#cc0' : '#0cc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Bat</div>
    <div class="R">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R">Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R">one
          <div class="R">blah</div>
          <div class="R">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R">two</div>
      </li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```