# Align checkboxes to the left, in a nested HTML list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nested HTML list. I am trying to align the checkboxes in a span that i want to align in a straight vertical line to the left.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>Bat</div>
    <div class="R">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R" <span class="chk">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete">
      </span>Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>one
          <div class="R">blah</div>
          <div class="R">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>two
          <div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried float, it doesnt seem to work.

**Note:** I do not want to lose the margins for the items. Just the checkbox.

Comment: u have used listing .so it will work as how list works

Comment: @Neel Yes. But assuming that I HAVE to use list. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="position:absolute; left:0" value="delete"></span>Bat </div>
    <div class="R">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R" <span class="chk">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="position:absolute; left:0" value="delete">
      </span>Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="position:absolute; left:0" value="delete"> </span>Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="position:absolute; left:0" value="delete"> </span>one
          <div class="R">blah</div>
          <div class="R">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="position:absolute; left:0" value="delete"> </span>two
          <div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This aligns all of the checkboxes in a straight vertical line outside of the list. Is that what  you wanted?

Comment: Didn't think the solution could be so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following css code and that will fix the issue.

```
li ul span input{margin-left: -36px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi arbaaz u can set padding 0 to ul element. **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anilram25/nr11edtq/)**

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li>
    <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>Bat</div>
    <div class="R">description</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R" <span class="chk">
      <input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete">
      </span>Cat</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>Rat</div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>one
          <div class="R">blah</div>
          <div class="R">blah blah</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="R"><span class="chk"><input type="checkbox" class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete"> </span>two
          <div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and use css

```
ul{
padding-left:0
}
```

**Hope this will help you**